# Angular2: HowTo debug "Uncaught Invalid Provider" Error?

Tags: angular

I have dozens of imports in my app.ts and after a huge refactor to align with the official Angular2 styleguide, I am getting the infamous Invalid Provider Error. I am using RC4.

```
reflective_provider.js:170Uncaught Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: undefined
```

How can I debug this? I need to know which imports / providers are wrong.

These are my imports:

https://gist.github.com/nottinhill/4d61beb9e3a05a6cfc11c65fcb4ad89a

This is my Ionic bootstrap:

https://gist.github.com/nottinhill/c8ef4f0f760af2f5a23ebeac35d6113b

Comment: What version of angular do you use?

Comment: Hmm.. this should work I guess. Try to use `new Provider(ReservationsService, { useClass: TestService })` instead of `provide` function. Or maybe that syntax `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }` but I think it is for RC5

Comment: Where in Code Do I use that? Also I don't think it will solve my problem. i need to know how to debug this.

Comment: Here https://gist.github.com/nottinhill/c8ef4f0f760af2f5a23ebeac35d6113b you have two `provide()` calls, try to change them to simple Provider creation or object with `proive` property.

Comment: Thats nice, can you help more what you mean with your solution suggestion? How to wrap that in code? object with provide propety...

Comment: Ok, then check what your provide functions return, is it undefined or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121012/discussion-between-frione-and-stephan-kristyn).

Answer (score 1):

In Angular2-RC4 `provide` from `@angular/core` is deprecated. you have to define your provider as below :

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [

    GoalService,
    {
        provide : TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
        deps: [Http]
    },
    TranslateService,
    {
        provide : AuthHttp,
        useFactory: (http) => {
            return new AuthHttp(
                new AuthConfig(),
                http
            );
        },
        deps: [Http]
    },
    AuthService,
    AuthServerService,
    AuthServerMock,
    AuthZeroService,
    AuthZeroMock
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The root causes have been circular dependencies in barell imports down in my modules hierachy. Solution was to explicitly import via '../shared/service/service.service.ts' instead of '../shared/' deep down in the modules and services directoried.

Barell Importing in higher hierachies with "../shared/index" works fine.

Comment: This needs more publicity. Time and time again this has been the cause of my service issues.